# "use strict"; + jQuery.getScript() = script can't export to global namespace

Tags: jquery, global-variables, getscript, use-strict

Suppose I have the following script, called `include_strict.js`. After it executes I should have `window.global1` defined:

```
"use strict";

var globalVar = {};
alert(typeof window.globalVar);
```

But if I include it from a block of javascript with

```
$.getScript("include_strict.js");
```

The alert says `undefined`. Why? What is going on here?

FYI, that's not what happens if I include the file using a script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="include_strict.js"></script>
```

Here, I see the expected alert, `object`. And if I remove `"use strict";`, then both `jQuery.getScript()` and `<script>;` have the same effect of displaying `object`.

I've created an example (https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-XXu97sL1Ckb0x0OHptTmVMY00/edit) to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It uses `$.getScript()` which uses `eval` to execute the script which cannot modify the global scope in strict mode:

> Second, `eval` of strict mode code does not introduce new variables into the surrounding scope. In normal code `eval("var x;")` introduces a variable x into the surrounding function or the global scope. This means that, in general, in a function containing a call to eval every name not referring to an argument or local variable must be mapped to a particular definition at runtime (because that eval might have introduced a new variable that would hide the outer variable). In strict mode eval creates variables only for the code being evaluated, so eval can't affect whether a name refers to an outer variable or some local variable:

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode

The solution is not using jQuery to load the script but appending a `script` element to the DOM. Note that you cannot even use jQuery to append the element; it will automatically use `$.getScript()` for it.

Comment: You beat me by some seconds ;-)

Comment: Very interesting. I just came across this issue for the first time and it totally makes sense. My problem is that I need to execute several scripts in order after they are loaded, so I need to know when the script has loaded before adding the next script. Is there a way for me to know when a script has loaded if I use the method of appending the script to the DOM? would .load() work?

Answer (score 2):

jQuery `eval`uates the script. "use strict;" inside `eval` changes the semantics of the code. That's why strict mode can be dangerous! Because in browsers which don't support it, your code does something else.

> Second, eval of strict mode code does not introduce new variables into the surrounding scope. In normal code eval("var x;") introduces a variable x into the surrounding function or the global scope. This means that, in general, in a function containing a call to eval every name not referring to an argument or local variable must be mapped to a particular definition at runtime (because that eval might have introduced a new variable that would hide the outer variable). In strict mode eval creates variables only for the code being evaluated, so eval can't affect whether a name refers to an outer variable or some local variable.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Strict_mode

The solution is to use `window.foo = "bar;"` instead of `var foo = "bar";`. And you should put your code inside a IIFE to make "use strict;" more predictable.

```
(function(window) {
    "use strict";

    window.globalVar = {};
    alert(typeof window.globalVar);
}(window));
```

Comment: It's not  exactly what I needed, but it made me 'click' - thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Process the response removing the strict mode before execute:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: scriptUrl,
    dataType: "script",
    dataFilter: function (data, type) {
        return data.replace("\'use strict\';", "");
    }
});
```