# Strange interaction between new Function and eval

Tags: javascript, firefox

Is there any reason why should this line of code fail?

```
new Function("eval('function foo(){ alert() }'); foo()")()
```

It pops an alert in Chromium as expected, but fails in Firefox (foo is not defined). Is this a Firefox bug, or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: This sounds like a strict/non strict mode thing - are you _sure_ you ran both of them in non-strict mode? (Chrome's behavior) or strict mode (Firefox's)? (Update: looking at the spec this might be an es5 vs es2015 (es6) thing)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I thought about that. I'm pretty sure I ran both in nonstrict mode. But strict mode shouldn't have any effect anyway, as new Function shouldn't reflect that (unlike a regular function).

Comment: While it's interesting that browsers behave differently, I still am left wondering "why do we care?" XD

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I actually need this for executing nonstrict code inside a strict code block. But eval has betrayed me... (I know I could replace new Function by an indirect eval call, but that looks kind of ugly)

Comment: @user2345215 yes, this is not a strict mode issue, this is a `Function` constructor scoping issue and possibly a global execution context one. The semantics of what gets put on the global execution context changed I believe in some edge cases between es5 and es2015 (es6) and this might be it. I guess we'll have to check the spec for a sure answer and file a bug (or find the bug) against the offending browsers.

Comment: This logs "object" indicating it runs in non-strict mode: `new Function("eval('function foo(){ alert(typeof this) }'); foo.call(6)")()` in chrome (in the console), the same for `new Function("eval('(function foo(){ alert(`type` + typeof this) })').call(6)")()` in firefox - so both browsers run this (correctly) in sloppy mode - now the issue is probably how function declarations are executed in eval in terms of scoping, I'll check the spec

Comment: Ok, I have no idea why firefox is doing this - both [es5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.2) and [es6](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation) (see 30 b in the section) say Chrome is right here unless I'm reading something wrong.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thank you for the references. I would certainly expect a direct nonstrict eval call to define foo in the eval's scope. But Javascript has surprised me many times before, so I wouldn't even ask this had the browsers behaved consistently. I guess Firefox is to blame then.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure yet - the ES2015 (es6) spec is pretty messy and to be fair these corners are almost never really explored - you can ask on esdiscuss (I can do it for you but I think you'd enjoy the interaction) and get a straight answer from the language lawyers. What do you say?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: My language lawyer feels that this is a Firefox bug. Neither in ES5 nor ES6 an evaled plain function declaration would not be usable there.

Comment: It indeed is as I have found the bug report https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=915805 It's almost 2 years old, so I don't expect this to be fixed anytime soon.

Comment: @user2345215: You should [make that an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)!

Comment: @Bergi I did something better. I fixed it. It's currently in the nightly build. I'll wait a few days just to be safe and then post an answer.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that `eval` does not inherit the global scope, so `foo` is created in a different scope than where it is being called. You can solve this by specifying the scope explicitly, either at the function definition or by passing to `eval`. I.e. both of the following snippets work as expected:

```
new Function("eval('window.foo = function(){ alert() }'); foo()")()

new Function("eval('function foo(){ alert() }', this); foo()")()
```

This behaviour seems to be related to strict mode, as explained by the answer here ["use strict"; + jQuery.getScript() = script can't export to global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776405/use-strict-jquery-getscript-script-cant-export-to-global-namespace).

Comment: `eval` is not intended to use the global scope, but the local function scope from that it was called (and in that `foo()` is called). Also your second snippet doesn't make sense, `eval` doesnot take a second parameter.

Comment: It does actually https://dev.mozilla.jp/localmdc/localmdc_3355.html. However the second argument seems to have been deprecated, so one should not rely on it being implemented (although I tested it in the latest version of Firefox and it works)