# Cannot load Script using jquery Ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to execute a function after a certain script was loaded so I load the script using an ajax call and on the success I invoke the function that uses an object that was suppose to be loaded already from that script and I get an error that this object is undefined. 
Here is my code:

```
function LoadInlineManualScript() {
  return $.ajax({
            url: "../Scripts/inline-manual-player.js",
            dataType: "script",
            beforeSend: function () {
                loader.hide();
                loader.unbind();
            },
            success: SetInlineManualCallbacks
        });
    }


function SetInlineManualCallbacks() {
            debugger;
            //Here I get the error!
            window.inline_manual_player.setCallbacks({
                onTopicDone: function (player, topic_id, step_id) {
                    console.log('Step was displayed.');
                }
            });
        }
```

And I get   `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setCallbacks' of undefined`.

I tried to change the call to use `async:false` but it didn't help.

Comment: What is `window.inline_manual_player.setCallbacks`? Because that seems to be the problem.

Comment: There is no code in your script that actually assigns a value to `window.inline_manual_player`. You ajax code is not doing that anyway.

Comment: @trincot window.inline_manual_player is loaded from the script file.

Comment: Change `success: SetInlineManualCallbacks(inlineUid)` to  `success: SetInlineManualCallbacks.bind(null, inlineUid)`

Comment: Please show the code in `../Scripts/inline-manual-player.js` which defines `window.inline_manual_player`. If it fails you will not have that object of course. What messages do you get in `console`?

Comment: It's not my js , it's minified.

Comment: @trincot, no I have other problem, I tried Leo solution which load the script, but it wasn't excuted. I tried this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230886/trying-to-fire-onload-event-on-script-tag with no success.

Comment: Don't do that. jQuery does all that for you, so stick with jQuery. What about your script file, can you share its code, even if minified, or give a link to it? Did you try the `bind` solution above?

Comment: @trincot , I stuck on this thing for so long... I tried getScript , I tried loading the script like in my question, nothing worked, only the way he showed me work.

Comment: I copied your code with my own referred javascript (which just creates the necessary variables you refer to), and with the change to `bind` it works, so you must have a problem that is not included in your question. Please provide the information of the script.

Comment: Also, which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @trincot jquery-2.0.0

Comment: What do you mean with the change to "bind"?

Comment: See my comment above about `bind`... 30 minutes ago. Did you read it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118733/discussion-between-offir-peer-and-trincot).

Comment: Does the `inline-manual-player.js` script really run before the `success` executes ? ... If not, there is no `window.inline_manual_player`

Comment: The JS does not set that `inline_manual_player` variable. It tests for its presence, but it does not set it itself. Do you have documentation somewhere that states it SHOULD set that variable? Or any documentation that explains what will create that variable?

Comment: It's weird, as I said , the way Leo suggested below does work.

Comment: It seems that because the script I am trying to load is with "use strict" I can't load it via Jquery. Take a look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776405/use-strict-jquery-getscript-script-cant-export-to-global-namespace?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: So, your question is solved?

Comment: I sent to the developer of inline-manual this link, he is on it. I will let you know soon.

Comment: @trincot , Marek is the developer of this tool.
Thank you for your help, take a look at my final answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is a combination of some answers I got here:

The function I use to load the script instead of using Jquery's `$.getScript` is:

```
   //Must load the script after inlineManualTracking object is ready.
    function LoadInlineManualScript() {
        loader.hide();
        loader.unbind();
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = "../Scripts/inline-manual-player.js";
        // your callback will fire when the script is loaded and executed
        script.onload = WaitForInlineManualScriptToLoad;
        // it will start to load right after appended, and execute of course
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    }
```

The script I load has `use strict` and it cannot be loaded with jquery because of the following reason: ["use strict"; + jQuery.getScript() = script can't export to global namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776405/use-strict-jquery-getscript-script-cant-export-to-global-namespace) like **epascarello** mentioned earlier.

Even after using **Leo's** answer I still had a problem with that object and that's why I use the following function after the `onload` event of the script.

```
function WaitForInlineManualScriptToLoad() {
    if (typeof window.inline_manual_player == 'undefined') {
        setTimeout(WaitForInlineManualScriptToLoad, 100);
        return;
    }
    InitInlineManualPlayerCallBacks();
}

function InitInlineManualPlayerCallBacks() {
    window.inline_manual_player.setCallbacks({
        onTopicDone: function (player, topic_id, step_id) {
            console.log('Step was displayed.');
        }
    });
}
```

**This works!** it's not the prettiest, but it works.
 The developer of `inline-manual` tool had responded here(**Marek**) and mentioned the fact that my site in under **"Test"** mode. There was no way we could know this can affect.

Comment: I see, inline-manual-player.js is still going to load other scripts, that makes the variable undefined even after itself loaded. Marek's approach to predefine options is a bit like Google Analytics.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. Function `SetInlineManualCallbacks` doesn't have a `return` statement. So despite issue 2, `SetInlineManualCallbacks(inlineUid)` should return `undefined`. However, `success` needs a **function**:

   ```
   success: SetInlineManualCallbacks.bind(null, inlineUid)
   ```

   Or old-school without `bind`:

   ```
   success: function() {
       SetInlineManualCallbacks(inlineUid)
   }
   ```

   But, looks like `SetInlineManualCallbacks` doesn't need any arguments, so this would be enough in your case:

   ```
   success: SetInlineManualCallbacks
   ```
2. It says `window.inline_manual_player` is `undefined`. Judging from the variable name, I think it's because you just loaded the JS file content, as **plain text**, but you didn't execute the content as JavaScript.

   You could use `eval` to execute it in `success` callback, but that's really a bad idea. I would probably insert a `<script>` tag into DOM, instead of using AJAX.

   ```
   function LoadInlineManualScript() {
       var s = document.createElement('script')
       s.src = "../Scripts/inline-manual-player.js"
       // your callback will fire when the script is loaded and executed
       s.onload = SetInlineManualCallbacks
       // it will start to load right after appended, and execute of course
       document.body.appendChild(s)
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Why you are loading by ajax? Let the browser do it.

The function **loadScript** insert the script on DOM and attach a callback to the event `onload` of script element.

```
function loadScript(href_script, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = href_script;
    script.onload = callback;

    // The same code used by Google Analytics
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    x.parentNode.insertBefore(script, x);
};

function SetInlineManualCallbacks() {
  debugger;
  //Here I get the error!
  console.log("Code Running");
}
```

Here an example:

```
loadScript("//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js", SetInlineManualCallbacks);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this

```
success: SetInlineManualCallbacks(inlineUid)
```

You are executing the method and setting whatever it returns to the success callback. You are not saying call this when success is triggered.

It should just be

```
success: SetInlineManualCallbacks
```

But I think there is an issue with the Ajax call itself, you are loading a script and expecting it to do something, I do not think the Ajax call is what you want. If the script is just returning `inlineUid` why are you using a script and not a JSON or text call. If `inlineUid` is global, than just read it in the callback method. Without knowing what is happening in the script file, it is hard to give a full answer.

Comment: So how can I send the inlineUid to that function?

Comment: Where does the `inlineUid` come from?

Comment: I get the script in the response.

Comment: Why is it a script, what is the script? Where does the inlineUid come from?

Comment: Ignore the inlineUid for now , I just want the script to be loaded.

Comment: Your code should be loading the script since what you are doing is basically getScript() under the covers.

Comment: I didn't use getscript because getscript doesn't have beforeSend event.

Comment: The script will be loaded, your issue is the fact there is no callback that gives the id. Where is that id coming from??? I asked you that 9 minutes ago, where is the id being generated?

Comment: I edited my question, even when I don't use the Id I have the same problem.

Comment: Are you using strict mode?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12776405/use-strict-jquery-getscript-script-cant-export-to-global-namespace That is why

Comment: I am not using "strict mode" and this didn't work for me even when I used "getscript"

Answer (score 0):

As someone suggested, Inline Manual is initialising itself in that script. You have your Site in Test mode, therefore there is an additional ajax request within the script itself, to check if the user can access it. So the script might load, but the inline_manual_player object won't be available yet when it is loaded because there are other things happening before it creates the object.

If you want to set the callbacks before the object is available, you can use queuing actions before calling the script to load.

`var inline_manual_player = inline_manual_player || []; 
inline_manual_player.push(['setCallbacks', my_callbacks]);`

http://help.inlinemanual.com/docs/queuing-actions

Answer (score 0):

According to your question you want to execute a skript, after another script was loaded correctly.

In your own answer using the jQuery "getScript"-function won´t work for you, so why not trying the old-fashioned way without using jQuery after all?

Create a new script-element, add it to your document head and set a callback-function on readystate.

```
function loadScript(url, callback) {
    var newScript = document.createElement( "script" )
    newScript.type = "text/javascript";
    if(newScript.readyState) {  //IE
        newScript.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (newScript.readyState === "loaded" || newScript.readyState === "complete") {
                newScript.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        };
    } else {  //Others
        newScript.onload = function() {
            callback();
        };
    }
    newScript.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild( newScript );
}
```

Now you can call the defined method and offer a callback-function, in your case this would be:

```
loadScript("../Scripts/inline-manual-player.js", function() {
    debugger;
    // should work now
    window.inline_manual_player.setCallbacks({
        onTopicDone: function (player, topic_id, step_id) {
            console.log('Step was displayed.');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the script wasn't executed at that time. Please note the callback is fired once the script has been loaded **but not necessarily executed**, based on [JQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).

If you want to make sure the script was executed, you can load the script synchronically on the HTML before you use it. If you do this, you won't need ajax, and you will keep your code simple. [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)

If you need to do it the way you have it here, then you can apply the observer pattern creating a [custom event](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-custom-events/).

Here is an example.

At the end of the file "inline-manual-player.js". You can do something like this.

```
$.event.trigger({
type: "fileExecuted");
```

Then instead of the success callback, you would subscribe to the "fileExecuted" event.

```
$(document).on("fileExecuted", SetInlineManualCallbacks);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

`success` takes a function and not a value. Unless `SetInlineManualCallbacks` returns another function, use `bind` and partially apply arguments.

```
function LoadInlineManualScript() {
  return $.ajax({
            url: "../Scripts/inline-manual-player.js",
            dataType: "script",
            beforeSend: function () {
                loader.hide();
                loader.unbind();
            },
            success: SetInlineManualCallbacks.bind(null, inlineUid)
        });
    }
```

It would help if you explained where `inlineUid` comes from.

Answer (score -1):

It would appear that inline-manual-player.js loads `window.inline_manual_player`  asynchronously.  This means the thread is allowed to move on *after that file's onload event fires* but *before `window.inline_manual_player` is loaded*.  Thus, you're finding that `window.inline_manual_player` is undefined for a period.  This is probably due to inline-manual-player.js making ajax calls of its own (or setTimeouts, etc. - JavaScript is an asynchronous beast).

Rather than setting an ugly (no offense) setTimeout, there are two potentially better possibilities.

## 1

If you're willing and able to update inline-manual-player.js, you could put something like this at the top of that file:

```
window.inline-manual-player-callback-queue = [];
```

... and later in that file, after `window.inline_manual_player` is asynchronously defined, add:

```
// I've made this an array, in case you'd like to add multiple functions to be called upon window.inline-manual-player being ready.
var queue = window.inline-manual-player-callback-queue;
var length = queue.length;
var i = 0;
for(i; i<length; i++) {
    queue[i]();
}
```

Finally, in your initial file, input the following:

```
function addCallback() {
    window.inline_manual_player.setCallbacks({
        onTopicDone: function (player, topic_id, step_id) {
            console.log('Step was displayed.');
        }
    });
}

$.ajax({
    url: "../Scripts/inline-manual-player.js",
    dataType: "script",
    beforeSend: function () {
        loader.hide();
        loader.unbind();
    },
    success: function() {
        // Because you've defined window.inline-manual-player-callback-queue at the start of inline-manual-player.js, the following will be available upon onload (aka success) of that file:
        window.inline-manual-player-callback-queue.push(addCallback);
    }
});
```

## 2

If editing inline-manual-player.js isn't an option, the initial author of that file may have already included something akin to window.inline-manual-player-callback-queue.  Check the documentation of the file, and see if there's not a global method or array you can add your callback function to, to have inline-manual-player.js call it automatically, once all the async magic has taken place.

Best of luck to you!

Comment: You could have saved some time if you would have read my answer and then Marek's.

Comment: You're answer isn't good, @OffirPe'er.  It uses a setTimeout, and doesn't take advantage of the pattern @MarekSotak and the docs recommend: `var inline_manual_player = inline_manual_player || [];`.

Comment: Marek sent me the answer I posted in private email.